# Is the form attribute target the same as asp.net crosspage postbacks?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback

Will I get the same behaivour setting the form

```
<form target="_parent">
```

or by doing a asp.net crosspage postback

```
<asp:button postbackurl="some.aspx" />
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the target is *where* the page is opened, while the URL is *which* page is opened.

Comment: @senyortoni: What specifically is it that you don't understand?

Comment: So the data, to which page is sended using both _target and crosspage?

Comment: @senyortoni: The request is sent to the postbackurl URL, the server doesn't know about the target. The response is loaded in the window/frame specified by the target.